# Is there a WordPress document on how to set up on this page?

Tags: discussion

Is there a clear answer to a question that asks "how to install WordPress?" or is that kind of question on-topic here?

Answer (score 5):

While this kind of question seems on topic to me, I think it's borderline too basic and realm of official documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Comment: …unless you start talking about Phing, Composer and other build systems. I would consider it being on topic if there's a specific task and effort shown and where it fails or lacks convenience.

Comment: Sure, such would make on topic and interesting question most of the time. :)